# Swift: How to get UTF-8 representation of characters (as 0xXX 0xXX 0xXX...)?

Tags: swift, encoding, utf-8

I'd like to get the UTF-8 representation of a character.

For example, according to [this webpage](https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+1F600),  should be `0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x80`, and UTF-16 is `0xD83D 0xDE00`.

I have tried this code:

```
extension String {

    var utf8Representation: String? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true), 
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

But here is the result I get:

```
 = \ud83d\ude00
```

Which is the UTF-16 and not the UTF-8 representation that I was expecting.

What should I do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.nonLossyASCII` conversion converts each non-ASCII character to a `"\uNNNN"` escape sequence, which is why your approach does not work.

`self.utf8` gives the UTF-8 representation of a `String`. Then format each UTF-8 code point as a `"0xNN"` string, and join the results with space characters:

```
extension String {
    var utf8Representation: String {
        return self.utf8.map { String(format: "0x%02hhx", $0) }.joined(separator: " ")
    }

}
```

Example:

```
print("".utf8Representation)
// 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x80
```